# Understanding DNS reports

Tags: domain-name-system

I need some clarification, I own a domain in moniker (let's say mydomain.com), in the DNS zone records I have:

```
RR Type    Name      Value                    Priority  
A          @         50.xxx.xxx.xxx  
A          www       50.xxx.xxx.xxx  
MX         @         XXXX.pamx1.hotmail.com   10
```

I can access my website by typing mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com.
Users who access mydomain.com are redirected to www.mydomain.com through .htaccess rule.

I did a DNSReport on [www.dnsstuff.com](http://www.dnsstuff.com/) of mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com and it shows the following:

mydomain.com:

pass in the **Reverse DNS entries for MX servers**

www.mydomain.com does not (actually a lot of other things didn't pass).

What is the right name to check?
mydomain.com or **www**.mydomain.com

The reason I did the DNSReport is because I want to know if reverse dns is properly setup, to avoid new emails going to spam folder.

Comment: `What is the right name to check` - What domain are you using for your email?  Do you have user@mydomain.com or user@www.mydomain.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

www.mydomain.com fails the Reverse DNS test on its MX servers because it doesn't *have* any MX records.

Unless you send and receive emails using @www.mydomain.com, there's no need to take note of email related tests for www.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

you domain is 'mydomain.com' www.mydomain.com is a host or in other words an entry in your dns record.

As far as the DNS server is concerned domain names are just strings stored in its configuration files.

You should actually remove the A entry for www and replace it with a CNAME entry, that would give you more flexibility in the case of an IP renumbering